# how do i get recomendations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

im currently starting to code, but when im following a tutorial and they write for example "application." and they get a window with lots of recomendations and their meanings but when i do it I only get like a couple of word i used before, i doesnt matter right, now but im concerned that when I start myself it will make things more difficult
I have tried to serch it but i dont see almost anyone with the same problem, and the ones i do, just aren`t answered

im currently coding in Csharp, visual studio code, with unity as a motor and also .net

sorry if bad english and thanks

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but it could help your research... The specific IDE functionality you're describing is called "intellisense".

Comment: It seems that you are talking about 
 [intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense), to enable it for C# you need to install corresponding plugin.

Comment: Intellisense will present more words to select from as you write more code for your application. Don't worry about it, just write your code and remember that many tutorials don't show all of the code that has been written so far.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about use of Visual Studio and out of scope for StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to switch your IDE to regular Visual Studio instead of VS Code. I've been using Visual Studio for a few years and recently tried to switch to VS Code and found the intellisense lacking a lot of useful things (GameObject, GetComponent).

If you decide to switch, download Visual Studio here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Then, in Unity, switch your default IDE to Visual Studio, go to preferences (Under the Unity Menu on a Mac or Edit on a PC). In External Tools switch your External Script Editor to Visual Studio. Check all the boxes, then Regenerate project files, here's a screenshot:

[Unity Prefs External Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhn7F.png)

I hope this makes things a bit easier in your coding adventure!